# How does `["length"]` work?

Tags: javascript

Today when I read undersocre, I found an interesting syntax **["length"]**

For example:

```js
"hello"["length"] //5
[1,2,3,4]["length"]  //4
```

This works in Chrome, Firefox and even IE5!

Is this a native js method or does it run in a array way like [1,2,3]["1"] or something like that?

Comment: it returns number of elements from array

Comment: "hello"["length"] is actually the same as "hello".length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a standard property of [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array): [`Array#length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

> The **`length`** property represents an unsigned, 32-bit integer that is always numerically greater than the highest index in the array.

Or a standard property of [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String): [`String#length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

> The **`length`** property represents the length of a string.

It is a different use of a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

```
[0, 1, 2].length
[0, 1, 2]['length']
```